# Issue with integration testing "composite unique constraint" in Grails/GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to make sure a `user` can `vote` a given `project` only once (no duplicate voting allowed). After some search, looks like there is a [composite unique constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/unique.html) to achieve this. However, I am having some issue in the integration testing. My domain classes are as follows.

```
package grailstuts

class User {
    String name
    static hasMany = [ projects: Project, votes: Vote ]

    static constraints = { name(nullable: true) }

    static mapping = { projects cascade: "all-delete-orphan" }
}
```

.

```
package grailstuts

class Project {
    String title
    Set votes = []
    static belongsTo = [ user: User ]
    static hasMany = [ votes: Vote ]

    static constraints = { title(nullable: true) }
}
```

.

```
package grailstuts

class Vote {
    static belongsTo = [ user: User, project: Project ]

    static constraints = { user(unique: 'project') }
}
```

Please note the `unique` constraint in the `Vote` class. Then my integration test looks like this:

```
package grailstuts

import spock.lang.*

class VoteIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    void "Testing uniqueness"() {

        given: "A user and a project"
        def user = new User();
        def project = new Project();
        user.addToProjects(project)
        user.save(failOnError: true)

        when: "The user votes the project"
        def vote = new Vote()
        user.addToVotes(vote)
        project.addToVotes(vote)

        then: "The user should not be able to vote the same project again"
        def vote2 = new Vote()
        user.addToVotes(vote2)
        project.addToVotes(vote2)
    }
}
```

This integration test passes without any error. But I was thinking this test should fail, because the user is voting again for the same project (in the `then:` block), which should not be possible based on the `static constraints = { user(unique: 'project') }` in the `Vote` class. Cannot seem to figure this out, can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the test is not validated.

Since voting is per user and per project (My assumption) as you said you need a composite uniqueness:

```
package grailstuts
class Vote {
    static belongsTo = [ user: User, project: Project ]
    static constraints = { 
           user unique: 'project'
    }
}
```

Your spec would be:

```
void "Testing uniqueness"() {

    given: "A user and a project"
        def user = new User()
        def project = new Project()
        user.addToProjects(project)
        user.save(failOnError: true)

    when: "The user votes the project"      
        def vote = new Vote(user:user,project:project).save()

    then: "The user should not be able to vote the same project again"      
       // def vote2 = new Vote(user:user,project:project).save(flush:true,failOnError:true)
       // or 
       new Vote(user:user,project:project).validate() == false
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Alidad! Couple of comments. In the `Vote`, whether I change the constraint to your way `user unique: ['project','user']`, or leave it my way `user(unique: 'project')`, both work fine ... so I was wondering what is the difference between the two? Especially what is the advantage specifying the `user` twice as in your recommendation? My second comment is if I used the `... save(flush:true,failOnError:true)` (which you have commented out in your reply), I do get an error as expected ... so I guess I should first validate before saving (as you have demonstrated). Thank you so much!

Comment: Another thing I wanted to mention is that in the `when:` block I had to include `user.addToVotes(vote)` and `project.addToVotes(vote)`, right after `def vote = new Vote(user:user,project:project).save()` to keep track of the number of votes for the user and project respectively. Thank you!

Comment: I fixed the user, that was a mistake. On the like that I commented that will throw exception, either you need to properly catch the exception. In spock is easy using `thrown` or if you do validation you know the object failed on validation.

Answer (score 1):

You're not testing that vote was saved to database. You should:

```
when: ...
vote.save()

then: ...
Vote.count() == 1

when: ...
vote1.save()

then:
Vote.count() == 1 // Constraint working
```

You need to write your test with two when and two then. When save first vote then Vote.count() == 1 When save second vote then Vote.count() == 1

You can to use unit test instead of integration test. The execution is more efficient.

Comment: This works too ... thank you very much, AA! I was looking for a way to validate the duplicate vote before saving, so Alidad's approach works slightly better in my case. However, you have made a couple of points that I really like. 'write your test with two when and two then' -- agreed. 'use unit test instead of integration test' -- agreed. I am a newbie to Grails (and to any web framework for that matter), and the book that I am using (Grails in Action) starts with integration tests ... so am just following along with some projects of my own. Really appreciate your feedback, thanks a ton!

Comment: Hi @tikka, I recommend you to read a recent book of grails. Grails in Action is about to publish second edition, covering Grails 2.0. You can buy it in MEAP edition. To read books of old version can hurt instead help you.

Comment: Hi @AA, "To read books of old version can hurt instead help you." -- totally agree, especially for a technology that is changing so fast. In fact, I did purchase the MEAP edition (GiA 2nd Edn) and that is exactly what I am following along for my projects. Thank you for mentioning this, I think this is really important for newbies like me to know what to read and what not to read. Great point!